# Using a inverter ic as a gate driver

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver

im working on a solid state tesla coil project,so i have a inverter ic

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/512032/POWERINT/TNY274PG.html&ved=2ahUKEwixwcSNn_LoAhULXSsKHeeuCcYQFjAMegQIBBAB&usg=AOvVaw2hCcPIbN5UCF-J_L_MQYgQ

Here is the datasheet for the ic so the question is can i apply a signal to the en/uv pin and use it to drive the gate drive transformer

Comment: Im just curious to know what can i do with the ic

Comment: Im just curious to know what can i do with the ic

Comment: You are just curious to know what can you do with the ic

Comment: Not really im actualy strugling with my tesla coil without a driver ic